# Unable to create basic skeleton from command line [ dart ]

Tags: dart, command-line

I am using instructions from [Get started: command-line and server apps | Dart](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/get-started).
When running `dart --version`, I get:

> Dart VM version: 2.8.0-20.11.beta (beta) (Mon Apr 20 14:33:01 2020 +0200) on "linux_x64"

Now, when I am trying to create my very first project with this command `dart create -t console-full cli`, I get back this:

> Error: Error when reading 'create': No such file or directory

Can somebody explain to me what is happening?

Comment: How did you install Dart and ending up with such an old beta version? Latest stable is 2.10.5 which you can get here: https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive (this is also the reason why the create command does not work... it did not exist in 2.8.0)

Comment: I'm just using the Dart that's embedded in the Flutter distro now.  That way, flutter upgrade gives me all the fresh bits for both Dart and Flutteer.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz The version of Dart that is bundled with Flutter is not the latest version of Dart. That may or may not be important to OP.

Comment: As of Dart 2.9.3 (the version I happen to have installed right now), there is no such command `dart create`, and attempting to run that command will instead cause dart to try and execute the file named "create" in your current directory.

Comment: You have already run the command: `dart remove --all_unnecessary`?

Answer (score 0):

After installing Flutter, this seems to work. I am still on the opinion this should not be the case (dart language should be independent in this matter from any add-ons, such as Flutter) , but hey, this might be only me.